# Pandas column to row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with below mentioned column names.

Dealer_Code Dealer_Name 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-03-01 2022-04-01 2022-05-01 2022-06-01 2022-07-01 2022-08-01 2022-09-01 2022-10-01 2022-11-01 2022-12-01

expected output columns

Dealer_Code    Dealer_Name  Date

001                 Dealer 1    2022-01-01

001                 Dealer 1   2022-02-01

i tried melt method but it's not working

Comment: The data for dealer_code and dealer_name will be same for all the records?

Comment: No, it's Diffferent